# Dynamic Programming: Implementing a solution using memoization

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming, memoization

As the question states, I am trying to solve a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/). The solutions are available online but, I want to implement my own solution. I have built my logic. Logic is totally fine. However, I am unable to optimize the code as the time limit is exceeding for the large numbers.

Here's my code:

```
let count = 0;

const climbingStairs = (n, memo = [{stairs: null}]) => {

if(n === memo[n]) {
    count += memo[n].stairs;
}

if(n < 0) return;

if(n === 0) return memo[n].stairs = count++;

memo[n] = climbingStairs(n - 1, memo) + climbingStairs(n - 2, memo); 

return memo[n];
}

climbingStairs(20); //running fine on time
climbingStairs(40); //hangs as the code isn't optimized

console.log(count); //the output for the given number
```

The code optimization using the memoization object is not working. I have tried multiple ways but still, facing issues. Any help would be appreciated in optimizing the code. Thanks!

Comment: `if(n === memo[n])` is never going to be `true` - `memo[n]` is either `{stairs: null}` or `undefined` in your code.

Comment: Also, what's up with that weird global `count`?

Comment: @Bergi, I am using count and incrementing it each time an "n" reaches down to the 0.

Comment: Yes, but why? If I call `climbingStairs(10)` then `climbingStairs(5)`, the latter shares the `count` of the former, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Bergi, no, I was doing this. When going downwards, if a tree has some repetitive branches (drawing the question on paper in the format of tree). I wanted to store the value of count for that repetitive tree in stairs and wanted to check if that repetitive tree occurs add that stored value of stairs to the count.

Comment: "*I wanted to store the value for that repetitive tree in stairs*" - yes, in the `stairs` in the respective object in `memo` (on the index for that particular repetitive tree). But not in `count`, which is shared by all trees!

Comment: @Bergi, I got your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you do not store a value, but `NaN` to the array.

You need to return zero to get a numerical value for adding.

Further more, you assign in each call a new value, even if you already have this value in the array.

A good idea is to use only same types (object vs number) in the array and not mixed types, because you need a differen hndling for each type.

```js
const climbingStairs = (n, memo = [1]) => {
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    return memo[n] ??= climbingStairs(n - 1, memo) + climbingStairs(n - 2, memo);
}

console.log(climbingStairs(5));
console.log(climbingStairs(20));
console.log(climbingStairs(40));
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for count value, you can memoize this way:

```
const climbStairs = (n, memo = []) => {
    if(n <= 2) return n;
    if(memo[n]) {
        return memo[n];
    }
   
    memo[n] = climbStairs(n - 1, memo) + climbStairs(n - 2, memo); 
    return memo[n];
}
```